# Inotify don't work on Docker for mac

Tags: docker, webpack-dev-server, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

I want to create Docker container for [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader). But inotify probably doesn't work inside the container. Therefore HMR is broken.

I use Docer for mac Version 1.12.0-rc2-beta16 (build: 9493).

This is my docker-compose.yml.

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

My Dockerfile is below

```
FROM node:6.2

RUN apt update && apt install vim inotify-tools -y

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app
RUN npm install
COPY . /usr/src/app

EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

and I put [react-hot-loader](https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader) directories in the same directory.

When I execute `docker-compose up`, I can access `localhost:8000` and my React project works well. However, HMR doesn't work even though I edit my React components in my local machine.

When I tried to edit my React component inside a container, HMR worked well.

In addition, I checked whether inotify work well or not with [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools). Then inotify doesn't work when I edit a file on my local machine. Of course, it works well when I edit a file inside a container.

Answer (score 1):

I restarted my mac then HMR worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Docker fs don't support inotify, you can fixed this by webpack config:

```
watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
}
```

github issue : [Docker support](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/143)